# Require identify report using number of columns in the excel report

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I have two excel files and I want to import these files to SQL temporary table.

**First excel file:**

```
 T1      T2      T3     T4  Total
 1,472   1,364   1,422  –   4,258 
-152.6  -152.6  -152.6  –   
 1,958   1,939   1,942  –   
-122.6  -123.7  -122.2  –
```

**Second excel file:**

```
 T1       T2     T3     T4  T5       Total
 1,472   1,364   1,422  –   12.2     4,258 
-152.6  -152.6  -152.6  –   1000.12
 1,958   1,939   1,942  –   50.23
-122.6  -123.7  -122.2  –   185.25
```

Is there any way in SSIS to identify the files on the basis of number of columns? I need to identify report on the basis of the column number.

Comment: you would need to create a preamble step using some code to check the number of columns in the Excel file and then direct the SSIS execution flow using the Precedence Constraints. Search online how you can code (e.g. in C#) the lookup

Answer (score 0):

Objects from the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace can be used in a C# Script Task to do this as follows.  This example outputs the file name and number of columns into an SSIS object variable (`User::SSISObjectVariable"`) that can be used to apply further logic and processing in the package, such as storing in a database table or otherwise.  The full file path is the first column in the object variable and the count of columns is the second.  Also be sure to add a reference to the Microsoft.CSharp namespace in the script.  The object variable will need to be included in the `ReadWriteVariables` field of the Script Task and if the source folder is stored in a variable (as done below) then add this variable in the `ReadOnlyVariables` field.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    List<string> excelFileList = new List<string>();
//get source directory
string filePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePathVariable"].Value.ToString();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);

System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("FilePath", typeof(System.String));
dt.Columns.Add("ColumnCount", typeof(System.Int32));

foreach (FileInfo fi in di.EnumerateFiles())
{
    //optional- check file extension and prefix
    if (fi.Extension == ".xls" && fi.Name.StartsWith("Prefix"))
    {
        //get full file path
        excelFileList.Add(fi.FullName);
    }
}

foreach (string excelFile in excelFileList)
{

 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); ;
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFile);
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];

 int columnCount;

//get number of columns
 columnCount = xlWorksheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
  System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious,
  false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Column;

//build data row to hold file path and column count
 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
 dr["FilePath"] = excelFile;
 dr["ColumnCount"] = columnCount;

 dt.Rows.Add(dr);

 xlApp.Workbooks.Close();
 xlApp.Quit();

 xlWorkbook = null;
 xlApp = null;
}

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

//populate object variable
Dts.Variables["User::SSISObjectVariable"].Value = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to import excels with different schemas, you have two approaches:

## (1) SSIS approach: Script Task + 2 Data flow tasks

In case that you only have two structures, then you can follow these steps:

1. Add a variable of type `System.Int32` example: `@[User::ColumnsCount]`
2. Add a variable of type `System.String` to store the file path example: `@[User::FilePath]`
3. Add a script Task with and Select `@[User::FilePath]` as ReadOnly variable and `@[User::ColumnsCount]` as ReadWrite Variable
4. Inside the script Task write a similar script:

   ```
   string FilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.toString();
   string ExcelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
                           "Data Source='" + FilePath + 
                           "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";

   using (OleDbConnection OleDBCon = new OleDbConnection(ExcelConnectionString))
           {
           if (OleDBCon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
               OleDBCon.Open();

               using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strcommand, OleDBCon))
               {
                   DataTable dtTable = new DataTable("Table1");


                   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                   //replace Sheet1$ with the sheet name if it is different
                   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Sheet1$"
                   using (OleDbDataAdapter daGetDataFromSheet = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                   {
                       daGetDataFromSheet.FillSchema(dtTable, SchemaType.Source);
                       Dts.Variables["User::ColumnsCount"].Value = dt.Columns.Count;
                   }

               }

           }
   ```
5. Add two Data Flow task, on for each Excel structure
6. Link the Script Task to each one of these Data Flow Task
7. Click on each Precedence constraint (link between tasks) and change the precendence type to Expression and Constraint and add the appropriate expression for each case:

*5 columns:*

```
@[User::ColumnsCount] == 5
```

*6 columns:*

```
@[User::ColumnsCount] == 6
```

6. Set the `Delay Validation` property to True for both Data Flow Tasks

**TL DR:** *In case that you only have two structures, you can add two Data Flow Tasks (one for each structure), then you can use a Script Task to identify the columns count and execute the appropriate Data Flow Task based on the Columns Count (using precedence constraints expressions).*

## (2) C# approach: SchemaMapper class library

Recently i started a new project on Github, which is a class library developed using C#. You can use it to import tabular data from excel, word , powerpoint, text, csv, html, json and xml into SQL server table with a different schema definition using schema mapping approach. check it out at:

- [SchemaMapper: C# Schema mapping class library](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper)

You can follow this Wiki page for a step-by-step guide:

- [Import data from multiple files into one SQL table step by step guide](https://github.com/munchy-bytes/SchemaMapper/wiki/Import-data-from-multiple-files-into-one-SQL-table-step-by-step-guide)